# Virtual interface shows up in ifconfig but no connections can be be made to it. What is wrong?

Tags: networking

I have a VPS set up with Ubuntu 12.04 on it and am having trouble getting a second IP set up as a virtual interface.  I've configured the interface as you can see from my /etc/networking/interfaces file here:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Interfaces brought up durring boot
auto eth0 eth0:0 eth0:1

# eth0 - Public IP, WAN access
iface eth0 inet static
    address 72.14.191.251
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 72.14.191.1

# eth0:0 - Public IP, WAN access
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 173.255.199.148
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 173.255.199.1

# eth0:1 - Private IP, LAN access
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.128.46
    netmask 255.255.128.0
```

The interface in question is `eth0:0` with the IP of `173.255.199.148`, no connection can be made to that IP. I can't even ping it. If I run `ifconfig`, all interfaces show as up:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f2:3c:91:ae:a0:8b  
          inet addr:72.14.191.251  Bcast:72.14.191.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:feae:a08b/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::f03c:91ff:feae:a08b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3664 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2908 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:330670 (330.6 KB)  TX bytes:970665 (970.6 KB)
          Interrupt:44 

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f2:3c:91:ae:a0:8b  
          inet addr:173.255.199.148  Bcast:173.255.199.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:44 

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f2:3c:91:ae:a0:8b  
          inet addr:192.168.128.46  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.128.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:44 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:141948 (141.9 KB)  TX bytes:141948 (141.9 KB)
```

Trying to bring the interface down or up doesn't help either:

```
chris@Optimus:~$ sudo ifdown eth0:0
ifdown: interface eth0:0 not configured
chris@Optimus:~$ sudo ifup eth0:0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0:0.
```

Nor does restarting networking:

```
chris@Optimus:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
 * Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces
 * Reconfiguring network interfaces...                                                                                                                                                                                                         resolvconf: Error: /etc/resolv.conf isn't a symlink, not doing anything.
resolvconf: Error: /etc/resolv.conf isn't a symlink, not doing anything.
resolvconf: Error: /etc/resolv.conf isn't a symlink, not doing anything.
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 4289
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0:0.
resolvconf: Error: /etc/resolv.conf isn't a symlink, not doing anything.
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 4361
```

Even a complete system reboot did nothing.  What is the problem here? What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you trying to ping from? What is the output to `netstat -rn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what happened, but I rebooted the server one more time and it now seems to be working. I'm really confused, but at least it's working.

Answer (score 2):

```
chris@Optimus:~$ sudo ifdown eth0:0
ifdown: interface eth0:0 not configured
chris@Optimus:~$ sudo ifup eth0:0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0:0.
```

Looks as if `ifup` was confused about the state of eth0:0. Easiest solution is to reboot.

```
resolvconf: Error: /etc/resolv.conf isn't a symlink
```

To fix this, run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```